# Error with opencv 2.1.40 with Eclipse C++ CDT and MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

Program in C++. I am using Eclipse and MinGW compiler on Windows7.
I am begginer to opencv and not able to resolve this error

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file                                             // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR is like this:

ERROR IS LIKE THIS:
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\opencv\build\include" "-IC:\opencv\build\include\opencv" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\Ganesha.o" "..\src\Ganesha.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib" -o Lucky.exe "src\Ganesha.o" -lopencv_core2410 -lopencv_highgui2410 -lopencv_imgproc2410 
src\Ganesha.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\Heenu\Lucky\Debug/../src/Ganesha.cpp:16: undefined reference to`cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
src\Ganesha.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: undefined reference to`cv::fastFree(void*)'
src\Ganesha.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:298: undefined reference to`cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
src\Ganesha.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: undefined reference to`cv::Mat::deallocate()'

Comment: you're trying to link the prebuild VS2010 libs. - that won't work with mingw. you will have to get cmake, and build opencv libs from src.

Comment: now that's what i call lame...

Comment: I am new to opencv and i am not able to start with.